# TabLayout, ViewPager

Tags: android

I am using a viewPager and tablayout to show user a multi page form. Every thing is working fine but what I want is for all the tabs before the current position to have the selected background color and tabs after the position remain unselected like this

[image]

instead of this

[image]

How to do this?

or Is there another way of achieving this?

Comment: paste your code

Comment: https://github.com/stepstone-tech/android-material-stepper this library fits your need, may be you want to try this.